# Make a jQuery function so I can call it in different events / scenarios

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have the following function which works great, it fires on blur and once validated will fire ajax to store it but I think I need to also add so when page loads and an email is already populated into the email input that it sees that and does the same action as some people auto fill this data so if that's the case might not ever change so blur and its ajax to save the email wont work.

So far I have replicated it, but don't think it works right... ideally would be good to do a new function so call within these events... but not sure how as JS is rather new to me but think I've done okay so far with what i managed to do.

So what it does is when email is entered in checkout and move out of the email input it will validate and if valid add to the abandoned cart information in case they don't complete order and we can follow up with an offer for the abandoned cart but feel that might miss out on some people that have their details pre-populated by their browser if you know what i mean?

```
if($('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').val()){
    var email = $(this).val();  
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length>0) {
        $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
    if (validEmail(email)) {
        //alert('valid email');
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email' ), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': email
            },
            caching: true
        });
        $(this).removeClass('cm-failed-field'); 
        $(this).prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
        $(this).next("span").remove();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('cm-failed-field');
        $(this).prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
        $(this).after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }
}

$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {

    var email = $(this).val();  
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length>0) {
        $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
    if (validEmail(email)) {
        //alert('valid email');
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email' ), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': email
            },
            caching: true
        });
        $(this).removeClass('cm-failed-field'); 
        $(this).prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
        $(this).next("span").remove();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('cm-failed-field');
        $(this).prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
        $(this).after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this:

```
function checkIt(field) {
    field = $(field);
    var email = field.val();
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
    if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
        $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
    if (validEmail(email)) {
        //alert('valid email');
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': email
            },
            caching: true
        });
        field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
        field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
        field.next("span").remove();
    } else {
        field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
        field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
        field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }
}

var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
if (field.value) {
    checkIt(field);
}

$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
    checkIt(this);
});
```

Comment: Getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on other areas of site which is breaking other stuff - seems its this part: var field=$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];if(field.value){checkIt(field);}

Comment: The JS files are compiled into 1 JS file so guess need some kind of condition on here so does not break on page if away from checkout or something?

Comment: Ok think maybe i worked it out, if you can confirm i done this right would be good: if ($(field).length > 0) {
  if (field.value) {
      checkIt(field);
  }
 }